# android: add components dynamically to layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a java app that adds views dynamically to a container panel as follows.

```
void addBoard(int ID) {
    BoardPanel p = new BoardPanel(myManager,ID);
    setAutoLayout();
    containerPanel.add(p);
    containerPanel.repaint();
}
```

When I try to convert this to an android app it hangs when addView is called. What is the problem? Note that the user could add a 1000 views (BoardPanels) if he likes so I can not use XML layouts.

```
void addBoard(int ID) {
    BoardPanel p = new BoardPanel(context,myManager,ID);
    Log.i("Info", "Going to add view");
    containerPanel.addView(p);
    Log.i("Info", "Added");
    containerPanel.postInvalidate();
}
```

Thanks

---

Update: Problem seems to be due to threaded code as Aegonis pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ViewGroup.addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) (FrameLayout, GridLayout, LinearLayout, ... are all extensions of ViewGroup).

For example, if you want a View to be inserted after the first already existing View:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutID);
layout.addView(viewToBeAdded, 1);
```

Comment: I used LinearLayout for 'containerPanel' and 'BoarPanel' as well. My activity has already started and views displayed. But later when I want to add more views to the container when a user clicks a button, it hangs on addView which implies that it may be impossible. I also want to clear all views in the container when a user clicks another button. Is it at possible to do such things in android ?

Comment: What you're describing should be perfectly possible indeed. I think the problem is not in the code you provide. Does this all take place in the main (UI) thread? Is there any exception or message in your LogCat that can possibly provide more information? If so: please update your post with it, it will help us/others to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I used threaded code which was the problem. But I wonder why it worked with the java code even though I didnt do an invokeLater on it. The android code worked after I added runOnUIthread.